# If statement with select in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement

I've having trouble to do a if with select, e.g:

In SQL Server I can do this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT  1 FROM mytable where "name" = 'myname')
BEGIN
    /*Do something*/
END
GO
```

But in postgresql I don't have any idea how handle this. I've tring some ways to do this, but unfortunately I have not success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for an [`IF`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) in Postgres (or rather PL/pgSQL) is `IF ... THEN ... END IF;`, so you can use the one you have and replace `BEGIN` with `THEN` and `END` with `END IF;`. Remove the `GO`.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM mytable
                      WHERE name = 'myname') THEN
  ...
END IF;
```

If that code piece is embedded in any PL/pgSQL function, procedure, etc. that's it. If not, i.e. you want to execute it ad hoc, you need to enclose it in a [`DO` block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html).

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                        FROM mytable
                        WHERE name = 'myname') THEN
    ...
  END IF;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an `IF` for this.  Just add the condition to a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM . . .
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT  1 FROM mytable where name = 'myname')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a, b,
  CASE
    WHEN a>0 THEN b/a
    ELSE 0
  END 
  AS c
FROM test
```

You can use `Case When` as of `IF` in SQL. It would rather work better